# UIDocumentPickerViewController selection in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uidocumentpickervc

I'm stuck on getting my DocumentPicker fully working. Right now it presents the view controller but I can't figure out how to wait or get the result.

In swift you just write the `void documentPicker(UIDocumentPickerViewController controller, didPickDocumentAtUrl...` method and when it's finished it goes to there.

But in Xamarin it must not be that simple. I've written that method, from the class I'm calling it from as well as in my `AppDelegate.cs` class and as well as in my `Main.cs` class. None seem to work, unless I've written it wrong.

What I have is this ....

```
public async Task<string> pickResume()
{
    string path = string.Empty;

    var controller = new UIViewController();
    var docVC = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(new string[] { "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document", "com.microsoft.word.doc" }, UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);
    UIViewController topController = getTopViewController();
    topController.PresentViewController(docVC, true, null); 

    return path;
}

 void documentPicker(UIDocumentPickerViewController controller, NSUrl didPickDocumentAtURL)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("done"); 
 }
```

`getTopViewController()` is just a helper method to get the top view controller so I can present the DocumentPicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, and it's a lot easier than I was making it out to be.

The `UIDocumentPickerViewController` has two `EventHandlers`, `DidPickDocument` and `WasCancelled` so I just assigned those to two different methods and done.

```
public async Task<string> pickResume()
{
    string path = string.Empty;
    var controller = new UIViewController();

    var docVC = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(new string[] { "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document", "com.microsoft.word.doc" }, UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);
    docVC.DidPickDocument += DocVC_DidPickDocument;
    docVC.WasCancelled += DocVC_WasCancelled;

    UIViewController topController = getTopViewController();
    topController.PresentViewController(docVC, true, null); 

    return await GetDocPath(new CancellationTokenSource());
}

private void DocVC_WasCancelled(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Handle being cancelled 
}

private void DocVC_DidPickDocument(object sender, UIDocumentPickedEventArgs e)
{
    //Handle document selection
}
```

Comment: In my case I had to subscribe to `DidPickDocumentAtUrls` too. For some reason `DidPickDocument` was never being called even if I put `AllowsMultipleSelection = false`